# Python: how to find values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two DataFrames, `df1`:

```
df1.head(6)
             t day  node    s   e   i   r   sm  em  im
    491325  100 0   0       9   12  21  95  2   4   17
    491326  100 0   1       8   16  17  140 7   5   40
    491327  100 0   2       8   9   17  143 0   4   38
    491328  100 0   3      20   15  37  259 4   7   60
    491329  100 0   4       8   13  11  85  1   1   20
    491330  100 0   5       0   4   6   37  0   0   10
```

and `df2`:

```
df2.head(6)
   node original     lat        lon     r
0   0   50405      1.299033 103.83828   0
1   1   50404      1.299033 103.83828   0
2   2   50405      1.299033 103.83828   0
3   3   50402      1.299033 103.83828   0
4   4   6101       1.299033 103.83828   0
5   5   9821       1.332867 103.95767   0
```

I want to update `df2.r` based on `df1.r` and I am doing a loop:

```
for j in df1.index:
    tmp = df2[df2.node == df1.node[j]]
    df2.r[tmp.index[0] = df1.r[j]
```

Is there a better way to merge the two DataFrames?

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge, but first you have to delete the dummy r column from df2:

```
In [11]: del df2["r"]

In [12]: df2.merge(df1[["r", "node"]])
Out[12]:
   node  original       lat        lon    r
0     0     50405  1.299033  103.83828   95
1     1     50404  1.299033  103.83828  140
2     2     50405  1.299033  103.83828  143
3     3     50402  1.299033  103.83828  259
4     4      6101  1.299033  103.83828   85
5     5      9821  1.332867  103.95767   37
```

Comment: Interesting, is not necessary add parameter `on`?

Comment: @jezrael well it is more pythonic becaues 'explicit is better than implicit' but my understanding is that pandas will infer the merge keys. EDIT: [The documents confirm this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) "`on:` If not passed and `left_index` and `right_index` are `False`, the intersection of the columns in the DataFrames will be inferred to be the join keys"

Comment: @michael_j_ward True (explicit is better than implicit), the issue is if r is in both, or if some columns are there unexpectedly. In this case you passing a two column subframe and we've deleted the r column in the line above. Generally, passing `on` is a good idea. Although if there's are other shared columns then these will be suffixed, so even then on is not a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), first select in `df1` only columns `r` and `node` and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `r` from `df2`:

```
print (pd.merge(df2.drop('r', axis=1), df1[['r','node']],  on='node'))
   node  original       lat        lon    r
0     0     50405  1.299033  103.83828   95
1     1     50404  1.299033  103.83828  140
2     2     50405  1.299033  103.83828  143
3     3     50402  1.299033  103.83828  259
4     4      6101  1.299033  103.83828   85
5     5      9821  1.332867  103.95767   37
```